# Removing a class pointer from vectors

Tags: c++

Say I have something like this

```
vector<foo*> f;
```

Now suppose I have a method like this

```
void RemoveFromFoo(foo* fptr)
{
   //search vector and remove if present
}
```

will something like this work ?

```
f.erase(std::remove(f.begin(), f.end(), fptr ), f.end());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. That's the *erase-remove idiom* for removing selected elements from a contatiner.

`remove` will move all the elements you want to keep (those which don't equal `fptr`) to the start of the sequence, and return an iterator to the first element after them (the first element you want to erase).

Then `erase` will erase the elements from there until the end from the container, leaving just the ones at the start which you want to keep.